# Ensure splitting comma separated string with numbers in string

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0

I am trying to split the following string

```
string v = "A: 1,5 ,B:2,44,C: 3,54,D: 5,11";

string[] val = v.Split(',');

for (int i = 0; i < val.Length; i++)
{
    val[i] = val[i].ToString().Trim();
}
```

The problem is that there are numbers with commas inside so the splitting is not correct. Is there a way to get for example in my array the correct values "A:1,5","B:2,44","C:3,54","D:5,11"? I am using C# 2.0

Comment: I think regular expressions would do the trick

Comment: Why not use dots as decimal seperator or semicolons as item seperator? This would simplify parsing.

Comment: This is just an example , i have large amount of data which are like that

Comment: Can you get values in easier to parse format (i.e. regular CSV or even JSON)?

Comment: Side note: be careful - `,` could be decimal separator or group separator - `1,5` may be either `15` OR `1.5`. May be good idea to learn in advance. Also check if `1,234,456` represent integer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your format *must* be a letter followed by a colon then a floating point number, with commas separating the entries:

```
string patternDelim = @"([A-Z]):"; // split on 'X:'
//                    @"([A-Z]+):" // split on 'ABC:'
//                    @"([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*):" // split on 'A1B2C3:'
string[] values = Regex.Split(input, patternDelim);
```

Because we've used a capturing group as a delimiter, it will end up in our output. So, at this point we've carved up the input into something like this:

```
A
 1,5 ,
B
2,44,
C
 3,54,
D
 5,11
```

Now we just need to extract these into their actual pairs of data:

```
Dictionary<string, string> pairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (int ii = 0; ii < values.Length; ++ii)
{
    // empty values are skipped
    if (values[ii].Length == 0) continue;

    string value = values[ii + 1].Trim()
                                 .TrimEnd(','); // remove any trailing commas

    pairs.Add(values[ii], value.TrimEnd());
    ii++; // use two each time
}
```

This will result in a dictionary of key-value pairs like so:

```
A = 1,5
B = 2,44
C = 3,54
D = 5,11
```

Which you can parse as you wish using the appropriate [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) or [`NumberFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx). Note, this will also work for all manner of decimal separators, and even if thousands separators are present:

```
Input = A: 1.000,5 ,B:2,44,C: 3,54e+38,D: -,11

A = 1.000,5
B = 2,44
C = 3,54e+38
D = -,11
```

Comment: The problem is if the Key is not just one letter and it is for example GLU: 4,5 or BA: 2,1 is not working

Comment: So modify the regular expression to something like: `([A-Z]+):`

Answer (score 1):

```
string v = "A: 1,5 ,B:2,44,C: 3,54,D: 5,11";

string[] val = Regex.Matches(v, @"\w+\s*\:\s*\d+\s*\,\s*\d+")
                    .Cast<Match>()
                    .Select(m => m.Value)
                    .ToArray();
```

Comment: No LINQ out of the box for .Net 2.0.

Comment: Yup, I missed that tag. Anyway, it should be trivial to convert.

Answer (score 0):

If the source string cannot be changed I would split on letters:

`v.Split(new[] {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'});`

or

`v.Split(new[] {"A:", "B:", "C:", "D:"});`

and than tidied up the resulting parts.

Comment: You can easily do this in Regex such that you don't need to be explicit as to which letters you use.

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to skin a cat. The question is if other developers on the project will be able to maintain regex expressions ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Another ugly alternative, works though

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string v = "A: 1,5 ,B:2,44,C: 3,54,D: 5,11";
    IEnumerable<string> result = Foo(v).ToArray();
    // A: 1,5
    // B:2,44
    // C: 3,54
    // D: 5,11
}

public static IEnumerable<string> Foo(string s)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    bool shouldFlush = false;
    bool firstIteration = true;
    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        if (!firstIteration)
        {
            shouldFlush = char.IsLetter(c);
        }
        if (shouldFlush)
        {
            string result = sb.ToString().Trim(' ', ',');
            sb.Clear();
            yield return result;
        }

        sb.Append(c);
        firstIteration = false;
    }

    yield return sb.ToString().Trim(' ', ',');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string v = "A: 1,5 ,B:2,44,C: 3,54,D: 5,11";
string outstr = Regex.Replace(v, "([A-Z-a-z]+)(: *)([0-9]+,*[0-9]*)([ ,]*)", "$1:$3_");
string[] newStringArray = outstr.Split('_');
```

Answer (score -1):

Quick answer (untested):

```
string[] parts = v.Split(',');
List<string> grouped = new List<string>();

for(int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
    grouped.Add(parts[i].Trim() + "," + parts[++i].Trim());
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This works perfectly and is much more efficient than RegEx.